# Creating 3d (Drag and drop graphics) based on data base tablesin Visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a parent table contains a cargo container dimensions and a child table contains Several cartons with several dimensions i want to create a graphic that contains both cargo container and cartons and be able to(drag and drop) cartons into the container. so I'm asking what kind of applications or controls to be used to achieve that.

thanks for any kind of help
Hammam

Answer (score 0):

For LightSwitch, see:
Drag and Drop and Events in LightSwitch Custom Controls 
http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/27/Drag-and-Drop-and-Events-in-LightSwitch-Custom-Controls.aspx